# Ayuda con array tridimensional

Tags: c, matrices

`RENGLONES` vale 3, `COLUMNAS` 5 y `cuantosCartones` depende la cantidad de cartones que el usuario quiera jugar. Necesito hacer que no se repitan los números dentro de cada cartón, pero como son 3 cartones diferentes si se pueden repetir en los globales. Es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe como hacer eso? El orden de la imagen es indiferente yo hice esto pero solo me funciona para 1 cartón, así que ni idea.

```
void cargar_carton_aleatorio(int m[][RENGLONES][COLUMNA],int cuantosCartones) {  
    int numero,comprobar;

    for (int cuan = 0;cuan < cuantosCartones;cuan++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < RENGLONES;r++) {
            for (int c = 0;c < COLUMNA;c++) {
                do {
                    numero = rand() % 16;
                    comprobar = verificar_repetidos(m,cuantosCartones,numero);

                } while(comprobar != -1);

                m[cuan][r][c] = numero;
            }
        }
    }   
}


int verificar_repetidos(int m[][RENGLONES][COLUMNA],int cuantosCartones,int numeroBuscado) {
    int pos = -1;

    for (int cuan = 0;cuan < cuantosCartones;cuan++){
        for (int r = 0;r < RENGLONES;r++){
            for (int c = 0;c < COLUMNA;c++){
                if (m[cuan][r][c] == numeroBuscado){
                    pos = m[cuan][r][c];

                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return pos;
}
```

//CODIGO 2 para ver como hacerlo para que el usuario ingrese los números, lo mismo de antes, solo me funciona para 1. y cuando quiero rellenar los otros cartones me toma siempre los numeros como repetidos cuando no tendría que ser así.

```
  void cargar_carton_manual(int m[][RENGLONES][COLUMNA],int cuantosCartones) {

int numero,comprobar;

for (int cuan = 0; cuan<cuantosCartones; cuan++){
    for (int r=0;r<RENGLONES;r++){
        for (int c=0;c<COLUMNA;c++){
            printf("Ingrese numero para: Carton %d pos [%d][%d]: ",cuan,r,c);
            scanf("%d",&numero);
            
            while(verificar_repetidos(m,cuantosCartones,numero) != -1){
            printf("Ingrese numero para: Carton %d pos [%d][%d]: ",cuan,r,c);
            scanf("%d",&numero);
                
            }
        
            m[cuan][r][c] = numero;
        }
    }
}
        mostrarCarton(m,cuantosCartones);
```

}

```
int verificar_repetidos(int m[RENGLONES][COLUMNA],int cuantosCartones,int numeroBuscado) {

    int pos = -1;

        for (int r=0;r<RENGLONES;r++){
            for (int c=0;c<COLUMNA;c++){
                if (m[r][c] == numeroBuscado){
                    pos = m[r][c];
                    //printf("Numero repetido\t");
            }
        }
    }
return pos;
```

}

Comment: Qué valor envías a `cuantosCartones`?

Comment: los que el usuario quiera pero pueden ser 1, 2 o 3 los valores de cuantosCartones

Comment: Si envías 3, solo te imprime una matriz?

Comment: no imprime nada, solo funciona cuando pongo 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu función que verifica repetidos utiliza todos los cartones, ese es el motivo por el cual solo funciona con 1... Porque como usas números del 1 al 16 en cartones de 15 números únicos es garantizado que exista en el segundo carton un numero que siempre esté repetido y tu código se queda dando vueltas buscando algo que nunca va a encontrar (un número que no esté en el primer cartón), la manera de corregirlo es cambiar tu función `verificar_repetidos` para que solo use un cartón.

Aquí agrego tú código con el ajuste y también utilizando tu mismo código hice una función extra para poder ver como la matriz se va llenando y comprobare que funcione.

Suerte en tu programación!

```
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <math.h>;
#define CARTONES 5
#define RENGLONES 3
#define COLUMNA 5

void imprimirMatriz(int m[][RENGLONES][COLUMNA],int cuantosCartones){
    for (int cuan = 0; cuan<cuantosCartones; cuan++){
        printf("Carton #%d\n",cuan+1);
        for (int r = 0; r < RENGLONES; r++){
            printf("[");
            for (int c=0; c < COLUMNA; c++){
                printf("%d\t",m[cuan][r][c]);
                if(c!=COLUMNA-1){
                    printf(",");
                }
            }
            printf("]\n");
        }
    }
}


int verificar_repetidos(int m[RENGLONES][COLUMNA],int cuantosCartones,int numeroBuscado){
    int pos = -1;
    for (int r=0;r<RENGLONES;r++){
        for (int c=0;c<COLUMNA;c++){
            if (m[r][c] == numeroBuscado){
                pos = m[r][c];
                printf("Numero repetido %d\n", pos);
            }
        }
    }
    return pos;
}


void cargar_carton_aleatorio(int m[][RENGLONES][COLUMNA],int cuantosCartones){
    
    int numero,comprobar;
    for (int cuan = 0; cuan<cuantosCartones; cuan++){
        for (int r = 0; r < RENGLONES; r++){
            for (int c=0; c < COLUMNA; c++){
                do{
                numero = rand() % 16;
                comprobar = verificar_repetidos(m[cuan],cuantosCartones,numero);
               }while(comprobar != -1);
               m[cuan][r][c] = numero;
               imprimirMatriz(m,cuantosCartones);
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int input[CARTONES][RENGLONES][COLUMNA];
    cargar_carton_aleatorio(input, CARTONES);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: y para hacer eso mismo pero que los numeros de los "cartones" sean ingresados a mano por el usuario? intente un par de cosas pero me sale

Comment: En ese caso borra el define de cartones (```#define CARTONES 5```) y crea una variable que guarde la cantidad de cartones que se va a usar que luego pasas a las funciones. Te recomiendo que uses ```scanf()``` para obtener los datos del usuario y guardarlos en dicha variable. Puedes editar tu código en la pregunta con tu progreso, para ver como ayudarte.

Por cierto, si mi respuesta resolvió el problema original de tu pregunta te agradecería si puedes marcarla como respuesta, de igual manera yo te seguiría ayudando en caso de que tuvieses algún problema.

Comment: en la parte de abajo subí el código

Comment: Tu función ```verificar_repetidos``` recibe una matriz bidimensional, pero cuando la invocas le pasas la matriz tridimensional completa. Cambia ```while(verificar_repetidos(m,cuantosCartones,numero) != -1)``` por ```while(verificar_repetidos(m[cuan],cuantosCartones,numero) != -1)```